# Should I use the future tense here?

Tags: future-tense

> Maybe you'll meet a girl who isn't interested in a long term relationship.

Should *isn't* actually be *won't be*? Are both acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think both are acceptable. They are certainly correct.

It may help to consider that we often use the present when talking about future moments in English.

> "When **you arrive**, we'll eat."

I think the main difference in your example is that "won't be" would imply that she starts to not want a long term relationship *from when she meets you*, versus the much more "in general", "she **isn't** interested", with you or with anyone.

Comment: The last sentence is exactly what I thought. Thanks for reassuring me!